# Excel: Copying formulas, keeping column values and increment only their row numbers

Tags: excel, formula

[image]

What I wanted to do is to copy a page to another page (e.g. copy to page 2, page 3 and so on) and keeping the formulas which is linked from another sheet, more like a database for this page. the problem is the page has several formulas and i want to increment only the row numbers of the formulas.

Like This:
Sample Codes from page 1,

```
Page 1
=AWS_db!$B7, =AWS_db!$C7, =AWS_db!$D7&AWS_db!$E7
```

I tried using "$" this symbol but it didn't work the way I wanted it to be

This is what I wanted to happen:

```
Page 2
=AWS_db!$B8, =AWS_db!$C8, =AWS_db!$D8&AWS_db!$E8
Page 3
=AWS_db!$B9, =AWS_db!$C9, =AWS_db!$D9&AWS_db!$E9
```

and so on

So every time I copy the page to another page I will not have to edit the formulas one by one, I got 1000 rows on the database page so I need 1000 pages

Comment: Could you clarify why you need 1 item per sheet instead of just having all the items on the one sheet? I'm not seeing the use case, and so while I might be able to answer, it might not meet the actual need.

Comment: There's only two work sheets in one workbook, the database: file named AWS_db and the result which is the Water Bill as shown in the picture above. I wanted to create several pages in one worksheet base on the number of rows in the database, the data comes from the same columns A,B,C etc. but different rows 1,2,3 etc. like in 1st page would show data from 1st row, 2nd page 2nd row, 3rd page 3rd row and so on

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can reliably get to doing this via formula would be to have the following formula in column A, and then copy it into columns B.

`=OFFSET(AWSdb!B2, $D$1,0)`

Column C would use

`=OFFSET(AWSdb!D2, $D$1,0)&OFFSET(AWSdb!E2, $D$1,0)`

You'd then put in the appropriate values in D1 to move the right # of rows down for the given sheet.

Another, possibly better, option would be a simple macro. Just record yourself copy/pasting the values to a sheet (plus any other actions you'd want to do like renaming the sheets). Drop that logic inside a `Do While` loop to iterate through the rows.